# How to store the full HTML table in JTable after parsing with JSoup?

Tags: java, swing, jsoup, html-parsing

I want to load the table from http://www.espn.com/nba/hollinger/teamstats into a JTable. After parsing the table with JSoup, I managed to load the table header, but I have problem to load the data rows. First I tried only the odd rows, but JSoup loaded only the last odd row, I don't know how to load all of them.
I tried to load from the first row using **.first()**, but then loaded only the first row, nothing else.
Here is my code:

```
Document doc = null;
try {
  doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.espn.com/nba/hollinger/teamstats").get();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
String [][] data = new String[30][12];
String [] header = new String[12];
for (Element table : doc.select("table.tablehead .colhead")) {
    for (Element row : table.select("tr")) {
        Elements tds = row.select("td");
        for (int i=0;i<12;i++) {
            header[i]=tds.get(i).text();
        }
    }
}
for (Element table : doc.select("table.tablehead .oddRow")) {
    for (int j=0;j<15;j++) {
        for (Element row : table.select("tr")) {
            for (int i=0;i<12;i++) {
                Elements tds = row.select("td");
                data[j][i]=tds.get(i).text();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The HTML table has 30 data rows, I want to load all of them into my JTable.
How to modify my code? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are ocercomplicating things. To get text from headers

- `select` table row `<tr>` holding header data
- iterate over its table data `<td>`
- get their `text()`
- store it in array

For data

- `select` all rows from table except first two since they are used for info and header (`:gt(1)` selector can be helpful here [`:gt(n): find elements whose sibling index is greater than n`](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax) since we want to get tr siblings starting at indexes 2,3,4,... in other words greater than 1)
- repeat what you did for headers but resulting array store as rows of 2D String array

Code:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.espn.com/nba/hollinger/teamstats").get();

//headers: pick specific row, get its td, convert them to text() store as array
String[] headers = doc.select("table.tablehead tr.colhead td")
                      .stream()
                      .map(Element::text)
                      .toArray(String[]::new);

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(headers));

//data: select rows with data, convert row to array, hold each row array in 2D array
String[][] data = doc.select("table.tablehead tr:gt(1)")
                     .stream()
                     .map(row -> row.select("td")
                                    .stream()
                                    .map(Element::text)
                                    .toArray(String[]::new)
                      ).toArray(String[][]::new);

System.out.println("----");
for (String[] row : data){
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row));
}
```